# Create a Rocky Linux Virtual Machine on Azure with Terraform

Tags: virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to create Rocky linux virtual machine on Azure with Terraform but my problem is Rocky Linux image,sku,offer and publisher, please help me,finding correct image.

storage_image_reference {

```
publisher = "rocky-linux"

offer     = "rocky-linux"

sku       = "8"

version   = "latest"
```

}

My Terraform module >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```html
provider "azurerm" {

  features {}

}


variable "prefix" {

  default = "tfvmex"

}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {

  name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"

  location = "West Europe"

}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {

  name                = "${var.prefix}-network"

  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]

  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {

  name                 = "internal"

  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name

  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]

}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {

  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic"

  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name


  ip_configuration {

    name                          = "testconfiguration1"

    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id

    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"

  }

}


resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {

  name                = "${var.prefix}-vm"

  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]

  vm_size             = "Standard_DS1_v2"


  storage_image_reference {

    publisher = "rocky-linux"

    offer     = "rocky-linux"

    sku       = "8"

    version   = "latest"

  }


  storage_os_disk {

    name              = "${var.prefix}-osdisk"

    caching           = "ReadWrite"

    create_option     = "FromImage"

    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"

  }


  os_profile {

    computer_name  = "myrhelvm"

    admin_username = "rheladmin"

    admin_password = "Password1234!"

  }


  os_profile_linux_config {

    disable_password_authentication = false

  }


  tags = {

    environment = "staging"

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create a Rocky Linux Virtual Machine on Azure with Terraform.

I created a `Rocky Linux Virtual Machine` using Terraform.

> Note: For testing I have used Rocky Linux free version, below are the details of Rocky Linux 8 Latest version.

You can find the `Rocky image` details by navigating to **Market Place > Search for Rocky Linux > Select the required image > Usage Information + Support**

[image]

Here is the updated `Terraform` code.

```
provider "azurerm" {
features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "Rocky-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "Rocky-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "Rocky-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "Rockylinux"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    admin_password = "Welcome@123$"
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard D2s v3"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "erockyenterprisesoftwarefoundationinc1653071250513"
    offer     = "rockylinux"
    sku       = "free"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  plan {
    name      = "rockylinux"
    publisher = "erockyenterprisesoftwarefoundationinc1653071250513"
    product   = "rockylinux"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I faced this type of error after applying above terraform module copy to main.tf file   >>>>>>>  Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 46, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example":
│   46:   admin_ssh_key {
│
│ The argument "public_key" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 48, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example":
│   48:     admin_password = "Welcome@123$"
│
│ An argument named "admin_password" is not expected here.

Comment: Remove the  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    admin_password = "Welcome@123$"
  }  and add the admin_password or add the block:
admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

Comment: Error: creating Linux Virtual Machine: (Name "Rockylinux" / Resource Group "Rocky-resources"): compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed" Message="User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'The plan with ID 'rockylinux' was not found. Try one of these: 1- Make sure the plan name is written correctly. 2- If this plan was recently created, allow up to 30 minutes for it to be available.

Comment: 3- The subscription you're using is associated with Market AZ which doesn't support this plan. Try using a different subscription. 4- The subscription/tenant you're using isn't part of the plan's private audience. Ask the offer publisher to add your subscription/tenant to the plan's private audience. subscription ID: bb6565aa-19d7-49a0-87ed-cb01692c7319. Publisher ID: 'erockyenterprisesoftwarefoundationinc1653071250513', Offer ID: 'rockylinux', Plan ID: 'rockylinux', Correlation ID: 'cb24cec2-2b11-1e54-7d01-9e55b8848567'.'"

Comment: i did it completely same but i faced above problem again

Comment: This means : associated with Market AZ which doesn't support this plan: You don't have access to create a private image which are Paid. Kindly contact your Subscription Owner or Azure Support Team.